# Change the closest textarea value on div click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

**What I'm Doing**

- At the moment I have a form with multiple inputs and one textarea.
- Just above the textarea I have a `div` called smilies
- This div contains clickable smilies

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input name="example-1" type="hidden" value="spongebob" />
    <input name="example-2" type="hidden" value="gary"  />

    <div id="smilies">
        <div id="smilies-box">
            <img src="http://example.com/smilies/smile.gif" title=":)" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <textarea name="example-3"></textarea>

    <button>Post</button>
</form>
```

**What I'm Trying To Do**

My aim is, when any image in `#smilies-box` is clicked, insert the title of that image into the `textarea` directly below.

Currently I'm trying the following jQuery but it's not finding the `textarea`?

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on("click", "#smilies-box img", function(){
    $(this).closest("textarea").val($(this).attr("title"));
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`closest()` is for going **up** the DOM hierarchy, not across or around. What you'll likely be looking for is [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) combined with `.parent()`

If you want to get really fancy, you can maybe get something like this to work for you :

```
$(document).on("click", "#smilies-box img", function(){
    $(this).closest(":has(textarea)").children().has(this).nextUntil('textarea').val($(this).attr("title"));
});
```

Comment: Updated with a really long jQuery solution to do it automatically. The easier way to do it is to do `.parent()` or `.closest()` to go to a selector you know will have a text area next to it.

Answer (score 1):

the [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will get you the closest parent that matches the selector.  Instead look for the form that has the teatarea.  Like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#smiles-box img", function() {
   $this = $(this);
   $("textarea[name='example-3']", $this.closest("form"))
      .val($this.attr("title"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the target textarea with the following:

```
var targettextarea = $(this).parent().parent().parent().children('textarea');
```